# MyBatis iterate list which contains hashmap

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

How would one iterate over a list which contains a map inside.

```
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list">
       ${item}.{key}    
</foreach>
```

this doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list">
    ${item.key}    
</foreach>
```